# codeigniter session user_data being reset

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter database session. I have a search navigation on the header of my page which contains a search from and to date and a text field.

I also have pagination on the page. I am using a custom controller (MY_Controller) and I am setting the from and to dates here. See below.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('News_model');

    $this->set_dates();
}

function set_dates()
{
    if (empty($this->input->post('from_date')))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('sel_from_date', date('Y-m-d'));
    }
    else 
    {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('sel_from_date', $this->input->post('from_date'));
        }
    }

    if (empty($this->input->post('to_date')))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('sel_to_date', date('Y-m-d'));
    }
    else 
    {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('sel_to_date', $this->input->post('to_date'));
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine even when I enter dates in the from and/or to fields and click submit, the correct dates stay in the search fields. 
However when I click on the link for the next page (in pagination) which basically adds another segment to the URL (i.e. mysite/news/politics/**1**) and loads the page, the dates in the session user_data are reset. I thought maybe the logic above for blank input dates was being executed again in this instance but that is not the case.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="from_date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From Date:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" class="form-control" name="from_date" id="from_date" width=10" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('sel_from_date'); ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="to_date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To Date:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="To Date" class="form-control" name="to_date" id="to_date" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('sel_to_date'); ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="go" id="go">Go</button>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the session variable 'sel_from_date' is already set .
If yes don't set it again. Try below in your controller:

```
if($this->session->userdata('sel_from_date') != '')
{
  // Do not set the session variable 'sel_from_date'
}
else
{
   // Execute the function $this->set_dates()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issues with the following code.

```
if (empty($this->input->post('from_date')) && !$this->session->userdata('sel_from_date'))
    {
....
}
```